# Correlation in simple CLRM regressions

Tags: self-study

Looking at a basic CLRM regression such as y=a+Bx+u, there is an assumption that the x's and errors (u) must be uncorrelated. Yet through simple algebra we can establish a simple equivalence relationship involving the 2 (x=(y-a-u)/B). Doesn't this equivalence relationship establish that the 2 co-move?

Comment: What do you mean by "CLRM" here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to statistics, but I would say that as long as the two functions depend on the same independent variable that they will co-vary. Does this answer your question?